# how to pass sql parameter as null value in integer datatype variable?

Tags: c#, types, integer, sqlparameter

how to pass sql parameter as null value in to integer data type variable ?

```
        StockBO sBO = new StockBO();
        sBO.Mode = 2;
        if (ddcmpanyname.SelectedIndex != 0)
        {
            sBO.Client_id = Convert.ToInt16(ddcmpanyname.SelectedValue);
        }
        else
        {
            sBO.Client_id = Convert.ToInt16(DBNull.Value);//Object cannot be cast from DBNull to other types.
       sBO.Client_id =DBNull.Value;//Cannot implicitly convert type 

        }
        ds=_StockController.StockGet(sBO);
```

i changed the code like this it gives error like i my comment check else part

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Try this,

```
else
    {
        sBO.Client_id = System.Data.SqlTypes.SqlInt32.Null;
    }
```

Answer (score 4):

It's not entirely clear what you mean. If you're trying to pass a null value in a SQL parameter, you should use [`DBNull.Value`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.dbnull.value.aspx) as the value for your [`SqlParameter`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlparameter.aspx) (or whatever type you're using). If you want to represent a nullable integer in C#, use `int?` (or `Nullable<int>` - they're the same thing).

You can't store a null value in a normal non-nullable value type variable. Nullable value types are still structs, but they wrap the non-nullable type and add a Boolean value to indicate whether it's a "real" value or null. C# adds syntactic sugar around it, allowing you to use the `null` literal for assignments, various conversions, lifted operators etc:

```
int? value = 5;
value = null;
if (value == null)
{
    ...
}
```

If that doesn't help, please give us more information about exactly what you're trying to do.

EDIT: Okay, so it looks like `StockBO.Client_id` should be of type `short?` - but then that won't allow `DBNull.Value` to be set directly. You should use `null` to set the client ID to the null value. Whenever you translate between objects and SQL parameters and results, you'll need to perform that kind of conversion yourself - if you find yourself doing this regularly, work out some helper methods to make it easier for you.

Of course, if you start using LINQ to SQL or anything like that, you don't need to worry about `DBNull.Value` - LINQ providers tend to support nullable value types directly.

Comment: I am very proud to see post..thanks ma i have updated my question please do check it

Answer (score 2):

Try [`DBNull.Value`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.dbnull.value.aspx); Like for instance:

```
dbParamId.Value = (object)MyID ?? DBNull.Value;
```

Answer (score 1):

from SQL to C# >

```
int number;
Int32.TryParse(paramvalue, out number);
```

from C# to SQL >

add DBNull to your parameter

Answer (score 1):

It is better to directly assign DBNull.Value like:

sBO.Client_id = DBNull.Value

DBNull.Value  is for all object

Answer (score 0):

Considering ParamValue contains the result of the query as an integer or a DBNull.Value, I'm casting it to *int?* this way:

```
var Result = ParamValue as int?;
```

To determine whether Result is null, do check Result.HasValue. Otherwise, use it as a usual integer, or Result.Value