# Inserted Null values into SQL table

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, winforms

i have a windows application form and i want to insert the text box values into sql database, some of them are mandatory others are allowed to insert null values. But i cant insert null values(in the case of int) into database.

```
 CREATE TABLE [dbo].[tblReg](
[Reg_ID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
[Sep_Status] [varchar](50) NOT NULL,
[Pop_Grp] [varchar](50) NOT NULL,
[Child_Address] [varchar](50) NULL,
[Child_AgeYr] [int] NULL

) ON [PRIMARY]
```

These are my c# code

```
private void Children_Save_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ss = SepStat.Text.ToString().Trim();
        pg = PopGr.Text.ToString().Trim();
        Add = ChildAdd.Text.ToString().Trim();
        yr = Convert.ToInt32(ChildDOBYr.Text); 
        createdid=SaveChilDetails(ss,pg,Add,yr);

    }

   public int SaveChilDetails(string ss, string pg,string Add,int yr)
    {
       string constring =Config.GetConnection();
       using (SqlConnection con=new SqlConnection(constring))
       {
           using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Insert into  tblReg(Sep_Status,Pop_Grp,Child_Address,Child_AgeYr) output INSERTED.Reg_ID values(@ss,@pg,@Add,@yr)", con))
           {
               cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ss", ss);
               cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pg", pg);
               if (Add == "")                                   //Problems are here
               { cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@add", null); }
               else
               { cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Add", Add); }
               if(yr==0)
               {cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@yr", null);}
               else
               {cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@yr", yr);}       //***********************
               if (con.State != ConnectionState.Open)
               con.Open();
               int createid = (int)cmd.ExecuteScalar();
               if (con.State == System.Data.ConnectionState.Open) con.Close();
               return createid;
           }
       }
    }
```

Comment: why do u have to pass null when by default null will be taken ?

Comment: but it is not taken default null value in the case of int

Comment: i think the problem is in convert Int part

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/3253147/2683275

Comment: Null and DBNull.Value both are different. If you are trying to set null value in sql parameter then you should try DBNull.Value instead of NULL.

Answer (score 2):

You can use **NULLIF** in your query

[**NULLIF**](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177562.aspx)

Try this

```
public int SaveChilDetails(string ss, string pg,string Add,int yr)
    {
       string constring =Config.GetConnection();
       using (SqlConnection con=new SqlConnection(constring))
       {
           using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Insert into  tblReg(Sep_Status,Pop_Grp,Child_Address,Child_AgeYr) output INSERTED.Reg_ID values(@ss,@pg,NULLIF(@Add,''),NULLIF(@yr,0))", con))
           {
               cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ss", ss);
               cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pg", pg);
               cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Add", Add);
               cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@yr", yr);
               if (con.State != ConnectionState.Open)
               con.Open();
               int createid = (int)cmd.ExecuteScalar();
               if (con.State == System.Data.ConnectionState.Open) con.Close();
               return createid;
           }
       }
    }
```

**Edit**

you are Getting error: **Input string was not in a correct format.**

you need to use **[Int.TryParse](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.int32.tryparse%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)**

Try this too

```
 public int SaveChilDetails(string ss, string pg,string Add,int yr)
        {
           string constring =Config.GetConnection();              
           using (SqlConnection con=new SqlConnection(constring))
           {
               using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Insert into  tblReg(Sep_Status,Pop_Grp,Child_Address,Child_AgeYr) output INSERTED.Reg_ID values(@ss,@pg,NULLIF(@Add,''),NULLIF(@yr,0))", con))
               {
                   cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ss", ss);
                   cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pg", pg);
                   cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Add", Add);
                   cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@yr", yr);                      
                   if (con.State != ConnectionState.Open)
                   con.Open();
                   int createid = (int)cmd.ExecuteScalar();
                   if (con.State == System.Data.ConnectionState.Open) con.Close();
                   return createid;
               }
           }
        }
```

**Update**

Try this

```
private void Children_Save_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int result=0;
        ss = SepStat.Text.ToString().Trim();
        pg = PopGr.Text.ToString().Trim();
        Add = ChildAdd.Text.ToString().Trim();
         if(int.TryParse(ChildDOBYr.Text,out result))
         {
            yr=ChildDOBYr.Text;
         }
         else
         {
           yr=result;
         }
        createdid=SaveChilDetails(ss,pg,Add,yr);

    }
```

Comment: i think the proble is in convert Int part

Comment: And What about yr = Convert.ToInt32(ChildDOBYr.Text); still error ocured here

Comment: @neel I have updated that too...please take a look at my updation

Answer (score 2):

You need to understand that `null` (used in programming) is different from the Database value `null`.

if you want to insert Null value into database table you need to use `DBNull.Value`

Try This:

```
 if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(Add))
 {
     cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Add", DBNull.Value);
 }
 else
 { 
     cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Add", Add); 
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `int? yr` instead of `int yr`

```
parameters.Add(""@yr"", yr.HasValue ? yr.Value : (object)DBNull.Value);
```

Reference : [Insert a null value to an int column in sql server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11018939/insert-a-null-value-to-an-int-column-in-sql-server)

Comment: @NullRefrenceException: And What about yr = Convert.ToInt32(ChildDOBYr.Text); still error cured here

Comment: @neel try yr=int.Parse(ChildDOBYr.Text);

Answer (score 0):

Run this query and you will know how it works.

```
create table #test(
  ID int null
)

insert into #test(ID)values(NUll)
select * from #test

drop table #test
```

Comment: and pass null value from stored procedure using DBNull.Value